# jQuery lightbox plugin available with Mac style options?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I'm looking for a stable `jQuery Lightbox plugin`, which uses Mac-like animation options. See [this page](http://visuallightbox.com/lightbox-mac-style-demo.html) for example.

Click on the first image and you'll see the zoom-animation originating from the original thumbnail.

Any idea which **free** plugin supports something like that out of the box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these two plugins :

- [Fancyzoom](http://www.cabel.name/2008/02/fancyzoom-10.html)
- [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out FancyBox

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery cycle plugin. It has various effects one of which is `zoom`. It might help you.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: I'm looking for a modal plugin, not a slideshow plugin ;).